# Formal Definition of Tree-Consistent

Tags: clustering, cart, hierarchical-clustering

I am working my way through [this paper on Bayesian Hierarchical Clustering](https://www2.stat.duke.edu/~kheller/bhcnew.pdf). I keep seeing the phrase *tree-consistent*. However, it doesn't seem to be defined anywhere in the paper. There is a description of the concept in figure 1.b, but it isn't a formal definition really. I have looked in other papers on the topic referencing the idea of *tree-consistency* and noticed that they don't formally define the concept either. Although I may be overlooking a paper on the topic.

Does anyone know of a formal definition for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, with the passage and figure below [Heller and Ghahramani](https://www2.stat.duke.edu/~kheller/bhcnew.pdf) provide the definition of `tree-consistent` to warrant the use of the concept in the paper.

> At each stage the algorithm considers merging all pairs of existing
>   trees. For example, if Ti and Tj are merged into some new tree Tk then
>   the associated set of data is Dk = Di∪Dj (see figure 1(a)).

[image]

Furthermore, on page 2 they say "([w]e elaborate on the notion of tree-consistent
partitions in section 3 and figure 1(b))." Indeed, the passage below from section 3 provides further insights into the notion of `tree-consistent`:

> **Proposition 1** The number of tree-consistent partitions is exponential in the number of data points for balanced binary trees.
>
> **Proof** If Ti has Ci tree-consistent partitions of Di and Tj has Cj tree-consistent partitions of Dj , then Tk = (Ti, Tj ) merging the two
>   has CiCj + 1 tree-consistent partitions of Dk = Di ∪ Dj , obtained by
>   combining all partitions and adding the partition where all data in Dk
>   are in one cluster. At the leaves Ci = 1. (...)